# Is it bad English to have two to's in a row?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, repetition

For example how would one correct the sentence "what website should I go to to upload the photo?" or is it correct already?

Comment: Although it is grammatically correct, the very fact that you feel uncomfortable shows that it is slightly odd to read.  It is quite common to put a dash "to - to" to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @Sam It is **not** odd to read, and dashes would be inappropriate punctuation and would possibly make it confusing. We do not punctuate for aesthetic purposes, but for readability and understanding.

Comment: It is aesthetic, but makes it clearer to read due to how the human brain processes words and sentences.  The meaning does not change.

Comment: I didn't say the meaning *changes*: I said - and maintain - that it might make it more confusing, or difficult to understand, because a dash in that position creates an inappropriate break in the sentence.

Comment: It is completely appropriate.  It makes the sentence evidently less confusing.  What possible other meaning could there be - it separates the meanings of the two parts.  "What websites should I go to - to upload the photo".  This is perfectly understandable and clearer than without the dash, otherwise people would be asking the question about a similar sentence with the dash.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sam That isn’t even a dash.  It’s a hyphen.  And it’s confusing. Don’t use it.

Comment: It's a dash, don't tell me what you think it is.  Cheers.

Comment: It breaks the "rule" against ending a clause with a preposition, but that's the kind of pedantry up with which I will not put.

Comment: @tchrist A hyphen or en dash with spaces around it is a common BE typographic convention equivalent to an em dash.  I suppose that's what Sam has in mind.  Agree that it's wrong, though.  If anything, the correct punctuation mark to put between a pair of deliberately repeated words is a comma.  Best to rephrase.

Comment: @Sam, while you may have *meant* a dash, you *used* a hyphen which is short: - A dash is a lot longer —

Comment: Sam, you seem to have confused *but* with *and*, *hyphen* with *dash*, *hyphen* with *comma*, *hyphen* with *semicolon*, *absurd dichotomy* with *deductive logic*, and *thanks* / *cheers* with something vulgar.   I have no idea what you think *evidently* means; evidently, it's not clear from your usage.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've frequently used *hyphens* in comments and answers on this site, when I've wanted to use an *en* or *em* dash, because I haven't found out how to create them. Advice please. (Incidentally, I regarded Sam's hyphens as dashes because I didn't think we could type dashes here.)

Comment: @TrevorD In Windows, hold down Alt and type 0151 on the numeric keypad. On a Mac, it's Shift+Command+Underscore. An en-dash is 0150. 0145-0148 are various curly quotes. 0169 is ©. 0189 is ½. Etc.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. I guess I should have known that (or at least looked it up). I'm familiar with doing the dashes in *MS Word* with various combinations of Ctrl+num.keypad-hyphen. I use Alt+171 for ½ and Alt+172 for ¼. (I've never used a Mac.)

Comment: It's not bad English but English is sometimes bad, and constructions like "to to", "that, that that" etc are arguably an unfortunate aspect of the language.

Comment: Not if you're a model railroad fanatic.

Comment: To which website should I go to do [whatever] **becomes** Which website should I go to to do whatever. Very common in **speech**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to correct it as it is perfectly grammatical. In fact the rules of English grammar are the very reason why the two *to*s occur in the first place.

It should also be noted that they are two entirely different *to*s, each serving a different purpose. It just so happens that they are pronounced and spelled the same, but removing one of them for that reason alone is like removing one of the words "what website" because they happen to begin with the same letter.

Sentences with three or more homonyms in a row are not unheard of, one of the most prominent examples being ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: I am getting semantic satiation for the word "buffalo"...

Comment: My personal favorite: ["James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher). But, "buffalo…" is all the more interesting for requiring no punctuation to be grammatical.

Comment: It is worth noting that the 'problem', so to speak, can be remediated by putting the first *to* at the beginning of the sentence: *to what website should I go to upload the photo?*

Comment: @Anonym should that be "to _which_ webite"...?

Answer (score 13):

As Reg says, it's perfectly correct, but if you don't like it, you could, of course, simply rephrase it:

> *Which website should I **use** to upload the photo?*
>   *Which website should I **visit** to upload the photo?*

Comment: or Which website should I go to in order to upload the photo?

Comment: or even, To which website should I go, in order to upload the photo?

Comment: Of course you could rephrase anything and everything. And as the comments and other answers here demonstrate, in many different ways, too. Thus making the question not constructive, despite its being quite clear: "is it correct already?" To which the answer is quite clear as well: "yes". Everything else is only muddying the waters.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider this sentence acceptable:

> The **maid made** our beds in the morning.

then you should consider yours acceptable too.

Still, the "to to" does look strange on the page, and it may be a distraction to the reader.  For this reason, and for this reason alone, it might be a good idea to reword the sentence.  For example:

> Which website should I go to when I want to upload the photo?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with this, I think you can build your sentence like "what website should I go to for uploading the photo?"

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it as

> "To which website should I go to upload the photo?"

Comment: But only if you follow the prescription about moving prepositions to the beginning of the clause in the rest of the text.  Mixing the two styles would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is fine, but you could get rid of "to" altogether with "On which website should I upload the photo?"

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is perfectly grammatical.

It is, however, a bit awkward stylistically to use two "to's" in a row. The second "to" means the same as the phrase "in order to", and by using that instead of just "to", this awkwardness would be avoided: "What website should I go to in order to upload the photo?"